# LocalSecondaryIndex using dynamodb enhanced client

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Dynamodb enhanced client has annotations for global secondary index but nothing is mentioned about local secondary indices. Can someone suggest what is the best way to use localsecondaryindex with dynamodb enhanced client?

Comment: LocalSecondary Index's have pretty much been phased out. They still exist, they can still be used, but they are kinda hidden in the UI and in general so its much harder to make use of them. You can do anything you would do with a Local with a Global however.